# php imap email body reading

Tags: php, special-characters, imap

I am getting my email by imap, but stuck up with one email in my inbox which have letter Â in it, and imap is not going to get its body. rest of emails going to read fine. Its header is fine, its going to read.

how I can get body of email with this kind of letters

Code sample is here

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mail server: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "UKPF - New Booking"'); 
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
$message  = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
```

Comment: One more thing I have notice that it is not going to read the body of email from a particular email address. should this happen with imap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using this quoted printable decode php function. In your case:

```
$message = quoted_printable_decode($imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2));
```

Answer (score -1):

I used to have problems with certain characters too in my php form, this helped:

I put this

```
"MIME-Version: 1.0; Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

in the `mail()` parameters. I don't know what imap is or how this works different, but hopefully this'll help.